# How does Apple deal now with development and production certificates for push notifications?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, testflight

Before the new build distribution system rolled, you can either signed your apps with development or adhoc certificates.

Now it seems the new Testflight only accepts IPA files signed with AppStore provisioning files only.

Can I still have a separate environment for sandbox push notifications?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still have a separate environment for sandbox push notifications, just not through the new TestFlight. You need to use an alternate service such as [Beta by Crashlytics](https://dev.twitter.com/crashlytics/beta-distribution) or [Hockey App](http://hockeyapp.net). And these services have the same limitations of the old TestFlight e.g. having to add your testers on to your developer account.